# Using javascript variables based on viewport dimensions to alter CSS properties

Tags: javascript, css, variables, resize, viewport

Learning javascript currently, cannot get my head around this, or why it's not working.

I'm attempting to use javascript variables based on the viewport dimensions to adjust the size of a div (so the div will expand or shrink specifically for a mobile phone's dimensions, or when you switch from landscape to portrait.)

Currently, in Chrome inspector, it shows the div at 0 0 (top left corner) with dimensions of 0px x 0px.
The console.log does provide dimensions of the viewport and advise if it showing as portrait or landscape.

In addition, I can confirm the image is in the directory I've set it to (because at one point I had this working but then I broke the background. Background currently working again).

Here's the javascript so far -

> ```
>    $(document).ready(function() {
>
>    //Variables for viewport height and width.
>      var windowWidth = $(window).width();
>      var windowHeight = $(window).height();
>
>    //resizeCloud function alters cloud image size by append cloud ID to include H & W variables
>     function resizeCloud() {
>        $('#cloud').css('width: ',windowWidth + 'px');
>        $('#cloud').css('height: ',windowHeight + 'px');
>        $(window).resize(resizeCloud);
>      };
>
>   //Will advise if app is in portrait or landscape
>   console.log("width: " + windowWidth);
>   console.log("height: " + windowHeight);
>    if (windowWidth < windowHeight) {
>       console.log("Portrait mode");
>     } else {
>       console.log("Landscape mode");
>    };
> ```
>
> });

And the CSS -

> ```
>  #cloud {
>    background-image: url('images/cloud.png');
>    position: absolute;
>    top: 0;
>    left: 0;
>    background-size: contain;
> ```

The HTML is just < div ID='cloud'>< /div> (sans spaces).

If there is an easier way to do this, let me know! Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes (: (I'll edit my main post)

Comment: Be clear. You want ur image size to be 100% based on ur viewport size right. Not sure asking like this. Just Created this https://jsfiddle.net/2n255t6v/ .  If so no need of any unwanted JS written for this. Handle it with css itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the event be bind, you should declare the function `resizeCloud` and bind it outside.

```
// Declare function
function resizeCloud() {
    $('#cloud').css('width', windowWidth + 'px');
    $('#cloud').css('height', windowHeight + 'px');
};

$(window).resize(resizeCloud); // Bind event
```

Also, pay attention to arguments of css method: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Anyway, you're trying use javascript for a CSS solution.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JS for that, CSS will do the trick. Just add "width: 100%" to your #cloud, and ensure that the #cloud is relative to a container which spans the full width of the screen.